# iPhone "View-based application" template: how is the view controller xib loaded?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm a little rusty on my Cocoa, and have a simple question. When I make a "View-based application" in XCode 4, I get a main window xib, an app delegate, and a UIViewController subclass and xib. The main window xib includes the UIViewController subclass as an object. But I don't see a call to "init" on this UIViewController anywhere in code or in the inspector. How did this view controller get initialized? I guess an embedded object's "init()" just magically get called somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [when exactly do Interface Builder items get instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764020/when-exactly-do-interface-builder-items-get-instantiated/5764080#5764080), I've provided an answer which describes the process of nib loading.

Comment: oh, does UIViewController awakeFromNib load the view controller's nib?

Comment: The viewController is in the MainWindow.nib, which is actually loaded by an entry in the plist.

Comment: Ya I know where the viewController object comes from. How does it load up its viewController XIB though?

Comment: All wired in the MainWindow.xib. Look at the File's Owner delegate, it references the XXXAppDelegate below First Responder. The appDelegate has it's viewController set to the view controller in xib. Select the view controller and open up the inspector, it references another nib file.

Comment: hrm ok. So it's the "NIB Name" property. I guess i'm just getting a little confused and thinking of things in a traditional "do x then y" sense instead of the declarative/pre-built XIB point of view. So if I wanted to load a different NIB with the same view controller, I could just change the "NIB Name" property value. Thanks!

Comment: nib files can get very confusing. to many not obvious/hidden connections in them. I really like IB but I tend to keep things simple. Let the code do some of the more complicated wiring.

Answer (score 1):

`self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;`

they are connected trough the MainWindow.xib file

if you want to customize stuff when a viewcontroller is loaded from xib/nib, you need to overwrite the method `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder` in the viewcontroller

example:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)theCoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:theCoder];

    if(self) {

        // your fancy stuff here!
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: I am asking how it's loaded, not how it's connected

Comment: see the first line in my answer? the viewcontroller is defined as `rootViewController` of the `window`. When you call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` the `rootViewController` (self.viewController) will be loaded.

Comment: What does "will be loaded" mean exactly?

Comment: `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)inCoder;` will be called if this is your question.

Comment: ok. sorry for the stupid questions i'm just having a hard time re-wrapping my head around the cocoa paradigm. when I freeze-dry an object, such as the view controller, into a XIB, how is that object "created" before freezing into the XIB? what if I want to initialize the object using a different "init" message than "init()", like "initSpecial(X x)"?